# How to plot points parallel to a given set of points which joins together to form a closed loop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a set of points which joins to form a closed loop(eg: a race track). Is there an equation to plot points which would form an outer parallel loop which is at a given distance(say d) from the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more of a mathematical problem than a unity problem. 2 steps are needed to be taken:
1. Find the equation of the curve(loop) first. One way that I've found out is  using **Lagrange polynomial** [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). There can be multiple equation, you have select the one that best suits your purpose.
2. After finding out the equation, you have to find out the parallel curve.
You can read through this to find the parallel of curve at a given 
 distance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve).